# How can I conduct meta-analysis on longitudinal data？

Tags: meta-analysis, longitudinal-data-analysis

Meta-analysis is a good way to synthesize data from multiple studies. Is it possible to conduct meta-analysis which contains a number of datasets, including longitudinal data (data was measured on the same subject for several times) and regular independent data?

Comment: What results do you intend to aggregate? If the study designs are different, then surely their results answer different questions and you can't just combine them.

Comment: On the other hand, if the longitudinal studies and the (presumably) cross sectional studies are estimating the same effect (for example, a treatment effect) then you could combine them the same way results are always combined in MA, by putting them on the same scale.